# Google App engine v Heroku

Tags: google-app-engine, heroku

Its been around 3 years now, Am using AppEngine, been great experience too as per as my application concern, recently i got few idea about [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) as PAAS, but frankly am not getting exact features about Heroku as i could use that for my next app instead of AppEngine,

Please someone help me out to give me basic features of **Heroku** and why should we use this service?

Great Thanks.

Comment: http://blog.tomtasche.at/2011/11/google-appengine-vs-heroku.html

Answer (score 1):

Heroku's website has all their features provided: https://www.heroku.com/features

Here I'm just going to list them out:

1. **Build**

   Once you push your application source code, Heroku prepares it for
   execution by retrieving the necessary dependencies specific to the
   frameworks and languages you use in your app. Heroku supports Ruby,
   Node.js, Python, Java, Go and PHP by default, but you can also
   choose another language by using a custom buildback.
2. **Config**

   Heroku lets you manage environment-specific configurations (such as
   credentials for backing services) separately from your source code
   for greater safety and portability. In Heroku, this data can be
   managed with config vars, which are made available to your running
   application as simple environment variables.
3. **Run**

   Sometimes you want to run one-off dynos on your app—run a script in
   your app's environment, use your app's console, etc. Using heroku
   run, you can quickly spin up a one-off instance of your app
   environment to run ad-hoc commands.
4. **Add-ons**

   Use technologies you love with over 150 Add-ons from the Elements
   Marketplace. Add-ons are fully-managed services, integrated for use
   with Heroku. They can be provisioned and scaled in one command.
   Add-ons provide services for logging, caching, monitoring,
   persistence and more.
5. **Buildpacks**

   Buildpacks are open source scripts for compiling apps on Heroku,
   specific to the frameworks and languages in your app. Heroku
   supports default buildpacks for Ruby, Node.js, Python, Java, Go and
   PHP, but you can also choose from hundreds of community buildpacks
   in the Elements Marketplace.
6. **Buttons**

   Heroku Buttons let you one-click provision, configure and deploy
   third party components, libraries and pattern apps. The Elements
   Marketplace lets you see what Buttons are trending from hundreds of
   open source repos, so you can find the perfect recipe to start
   building apps quickly.
7. **Deploy with Git**

   strong textUse git to deploy apps to Heroku in one command. We'll
   build and run the source application, handling compilation,
   dependencies, assets and executables so you can focus on code. Code
   pushed to the heroku remote will be live and running on the platform
   quickly. Learn More.
8. **Heroku Fork**

   Heroku fork creates a duplicate instance of your application,
   running on Heroku immediately. It can be used to rapidly spin up new
   application environments, demonstrate feature branches on a running
   app, or migrate apps to Heroku Europe.
9. **Releases**

   Whenever you deploy changes to your app, Heroku creates a new
   release of your app. We keep your app's release history, and you can
   list all of your releases, who made them, and when. And if something
   goes wrong in a release, use the rollback command to roll back to
   the latest release or a specific release until you can fix the
   problem. Learn more.
10. **Regions**

    Heroku has two geographic regions — US and Europe — so you can
    deploy apps closer to your users, with less latency. Learn More.

I'm just started to use Heroku, but one feature I like about is the **Config** feature. It comes pretty handy when configuring my Flask App using the environment variables. Check out this [tutorial](
*Personal comments: This is pretty handy when configuring the python Flask app. For example, check out this great [tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/flask-by-example-part-1-project-setup).